# How to return IList<T> in Lambda query for this program

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have Employee class, which has 3 properties, ID, Name, HireDate.

```
var employees = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee {Employeeid = 1, EmployeeName = "Ravi", HireDate = new DateTime(2007, 2, 23)},
    new Employee {Employeeid = 2, EmployeeName = "Scott", HireDate = new DateTime(2007, 2, 23)},
    new Employee {Employeeid = 3, EmployeeName = "Megan", HireDate = new DateTime(2003, 9, 2)},
    new Employee {Employeeid = 4, EmployeeName = "Raj", HireDate = new DateTime(2010, 9, 23)},
    new Employee {Employeeid = 5, EmployeeName = "Major", HireDate = new DateTime(2003, 9, 23)},
    new Employee {Employeeid = 6, EmployeeName = "Kernel", HireDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 3)},
};
```

Now I need to write a function which returns an IList for particular ID. Based on Id I need all details of particular employee info.  I don't know where I'm missing it, its showing some error regarding return type. "Cannot convert bool to IList". Please help me.

```
 private IList<Employee> GetDetails(List<Employee> list, int id)
{
    return list.Select(e => e.Employeeid == id)
}
```

which i'll use this function for Action delegate to write on console.

```
var query= GetDetails(list, 4);
```

for this query i need to invoke print delegate.

```
Action<Employee> print = e => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Hired on  {1}",e.EmployeeName,e.HireDate));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `Where`, not `Select`, and need to use `ToList()` to return an `IList<Employee>`:

```
private IList<Employee> GetDetails(List<Employee> list, int id)
{
    return list.Where(e => e.Employeeid == id).ToList();
}
```

For your edit, you could use a standard `foreach`:

```
foreach (var employee in GetDetails(employees))
{
    print(employee);
}
```

Alternatively, if you were to return a `List<Employee>` from `GetDetails()` instead, you could use the `ForEach()` method on `List<T>` to perform the action:

```
private List<Employee> GetDetails(List<Employee> list, int id)
{
    return list.Where(e => e.Employeeid == id).ToList();
}
```

Used as:

```
GetDetails(employees).ForEach(print);
```

Comment: How about returning IEumerable<employee>

Comment: If that's appropriate, then you can simply change the return type to IEnumerable<Employee> (in which case, you don't necessarily need the ToList() since the Where() itself returns IEnumerable<Employee>).

Comment: ya,itsworking, but now i've to use this for Action<t> delegate to print details.how can i use this ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that each `Employee` has a unique ID, so why do you want to return a `List` ?
Your method will only return one employee, since you do not have multiple `Employee` instances for a given ID.

You can use the LINQ FirstOrDefault method:

```
private Employee GetEmployee( IEnumerable<Employee> list, int id )
{
     return list.FirstOrDefault( e => e.EmployeeId == id);
}
```

Comment: how to return ienumerable<employee> for this function if i need

Comment: Then, use Where instead of FirstOrDefault (and change the return type of the method).  But I'll doubt if you'd ever need to return an IEnumerable in this case; it would mean your Id is not unique and that's no good.

Comment: id will be unique, but i need this details for Action<t> delegate to write to console output. likethis  Action<Employee> print = e => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Hired on  {1}",e.EmployeeName,e.HireDate));

Answer (score 1):

just change this line

```
 private IList<Employee> GetDetails(List<Employee> list, int id) 
 { 
     return list.Select(e => e.Employeeid == id) 
 }
```

to

```
 private IList<Employee> GetDetails(List<Employee> list, int id) 
 { 
    return list.Where(e => e.Employeeid == id).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: how to return ienumerable<employee> if i need to.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the employees, `Select` is *projecting* **true** (if `EmployeeId` is equal to `id`) or **false** (if `EmployeeId` is not). So, you'll end up with an enumerable of bools...
What you need is a `Where`, like Frederik and Iridium say.